# How to re-index multiple Elastic Search types into a new index with a single type?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am upgrading from ElasticSearch 5.6 to 6.0 and I have standard logstash-* indexes. In those indexes I have multiple (doc) types "attachmentsDbStats" and "attachmentsFileStats" which have the same schema. The only difference is the value of _type and type. I have created a new index attachments-* where the type is "attachement" and I want to reindex documents of both types into the new index. Obviously b/c of the new single type restriction in 6.0, both need to have the same type. I have update all of the documents in my old index such that the "type" field has a value "attachment." When I run reindex I am not able to upload the documents due to the restriction on the single type. I have attempted to update the _type field in the old indexes but that is immutable. Any ideas how to reindex and convert the type during the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "logstash-*"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "attachments-*"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
    ctx._id = ctx._type + "-" + ctx._id;
    ctx._source.type = ctx._type;
    ctx._type = "attachement";
"""
  }
}
```

Combining `_type` and `_id` into the new `_id` field, so it's definitely unique. Move the `_type` field to a custom `type`. And set the `_type` to "attachement" (note that the convention used by Elastic uses "doc" as the default type, but you can pick whatever you want as long as there is a single type).

Comment: Great! If it solved your problem, please mark the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tip. Fixing some of the spelling errors I had above this did the trick:

```
 POST _reindex {
  "source": {
    "index": "logstash-*",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "term": {
            "type": "attachments"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "attachments.old"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._id = ctx._type + '-' + ctx._id; ctx._source.type = ctx._type; ctx._type = 'attachments';"
  }
}
```